# How to calculate the beam size of a laser from the end of a fibre?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, laser, structural-beam

I need to calculate the beam size of the laser beam after a distance $z = 2$ mm from the fibre tip.

I know the numerical aperture NA = 0.59, half angle $\theta = 36$ degrees, and core diameter $d_\mathrm{core} = 5$ mm of the fibre.

Not sure why I haven't been able to find an answer for this, so please can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: For the record, I tagged this with [tag: homework-and-exercises] but I do not mean to say this is homework. It is requesting the tools necessary to work out a physics problem for oneself. According to our policy, it falls under this tag and it is decently proposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like a high NA for a fiber. Usually they are NA = 0.22 or so. But assuming that you have an NA = 0.59, you can calculate the angle NA = Sin(theta), so theta = 36.15 degrees (half angle of cone). At a distance of 2 mm away, you can calculate the half diameter of the illuminated spot with Y = z Tan(theta) = 1.461 mm. So the spot diameter will be twice that value at a distance of 2mm. D = 2.923 mm.
I'm not sure what you mean by 5mm of the fiber. Do you mean that the core of the fiber is 5mm diameter? That's a light pipe, not a fiber. But if you want to be picky about it, you can add the fiber diameter to the calculated spot diameter above. Usually fibers are around 0.01 to 0.1 mm diameter, so it won't change the spot diameter answer much. Also, be aware that this is a first order calculation. Spot diameters are subject to definitions as to where the actual edge of the spot resides. They are not sharp cutoffs. But using basic trig the above calculation should suffice.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response! To clarify on the points you brought up, I'm actually using a liquid light guide but I thought I would just simplify it by saying a fibre. And the '5mm of the fibre' doesn't read correctly, I was just listing all of the properties 'of the fibre', apologies. As for the answer, thank you very much for explaining this. So adding the increase in spot size to the original core diameter will give me the total spot size? Also, does the first order calculation refer to the $1/e^2$ width of the beam?